# How to add class to random element in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, requestanimationframe

I have a ul with some `li`'s inside. 
I want to randomly select an `li` and add an `.active` class for 1second, then remove `.active` class and randomly select a next `li`.

I am trying to do this without the use of setInterval or Timeout, so I have tried using requestAnimationFrame although I think my logic with javascript is not quite right on randomizing.

Currently I have it working but it selects the same `li` each time the function is called again.

```
<ul>
  <li class="light active"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
(function() {

var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lights.length - 1)) + 0;
var randomLight = lights[random];

function repeatOften() {
  randomLight.classList += randomLight.classList ? ' active' : ' light';
  requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}
requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);

})();
```

Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/PJjapX?editors=0010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And why exactly are you trying to avoid `setInterval()`?

Comment: You never start running your `repeatOften()` function. So it's not repeatedly setting the `active` class, it just only applies it to the very first case.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Avoid layout thrashing, inconsistent delay intervals and if the user changes tabs it affects the timing. From what i've read requestAnimationFrame is the way to go and i'm trying to familiarize myself :)

Comment: @adjit yes that was a typo, i've added in an edit. The referenced pen is correct as well.

Comment: I see why you want to avoid `setInterval` but why avoid `setTimeout`?
It doesn't cause layout thrashing by itself (changing a class does change the DOM and if the class requires a layout, it will cause a layout no matter if `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout`)

Comment: @geekonaut for sure, but there are many reasons why I would like to avoid setTimeout as well. requestAnimationFrame runs on 60fps, animations with it won't have any flicker or shear, and importantly no frame skip. Although this current animation won't really face those issues, I am trying to familiarize myself with requestAnimationFrame. Secondly, setTimeout only updates the screen when it wants to, not when the computer is able to, forcing the browser to juggle redrawing the anim vs page.

Comment: While this is generally not wrong - and I would advocate using `requestAnimationFrame` over `setTimeout` normally, here it's not the right thing to do.

In your pen, you're not changing any properties in an animation per frame in JS, you are triggering a CSS animation that is unrelated to `requestAnimationFrame`.

You want to run a function once a second & that's what `setTimeout` is made for.

Comment: @geekonaut I agree, I think you're right about that. Do you know specific type of animation where you would use RequestAnimationFrame over setTimeout? I agree this wasn't the best example to go off of to try it.

Comment: say, for instance, you want to move an element. Here's an example of that: https://codepen.io/AVGP/pen/NagLGX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right choice to run a function in a more-or-less known time in the future is `setTimeout`. `requestAnimationFrame` is meant for something that should run as often as is feasible without interrupting the render loop, say 60 times a second (aka "at 60 fps").

In your case you have a relatively slow update rate of once a second, so `setTimeout` isn't hurting.

You probably want to keep track of two elements: The one you're changing and the one you previously changed, so you can reset it.

Also, `classList.toggle` comes in handy as it adds or removes a class, based on if it's already present or not.

```
(function() {
  var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
  var previousLight = null;

  function repeatOften() {
    if (previousLight) previousLight.classList.toggle('active')

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lights.length - 1)) + 0;
    var randomLight = lights[random];
    randomLight.classList.toggle(randomLight);
    previousLight = randomLight;
    setTimeout(repeatOften, 1000);
  }

  setTimeout(repeatOften, 1000);
})();
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/AVGP/pen/JrJZmp?editors=0010) is the updated (and slightly changed) pen.

Comment: Voted correct as it's the best practice solution for my question even though it did not use RequestAnimationFrame. The answer below by sven is what I was looking for but is not the correct solution for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update which light to blink every time the function runs.  To make a different light change every second, check if the animation frame time has been a second.

```js
(function repeatOften(ts) {
  if (ts % 1000 < 10) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove('active');
    var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
    lights[Math.floor(Math.random() * lights.length)].classList.add('active');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
})();
```

```css
li {
  background: 1px black
}

li.active {
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="light active"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to do this without the use of setInterval or Timeout

You can use `animationend` event to call same function when current CSS animation completes

```js
function fn() {
  var lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lights.length);
  var randomLight = lights[random];
  repeatOften(randomLight)
};

function repeatOften(randomLight) {
  randomLight.className = "light active";
  randomLight.addEventListener("animationend", blink)
}

function blink() {
  this.className = "light";
  this.removeEventListener("animationend", blink);
  fn();
}

// handle first `li`
document.querySelector(".light.active")
.addEventListener("animationend", blink)
```

```css
.light.active {
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="light active"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
  <li class="light"></li>
</ul>
```